# KKT conditions for nonlinear problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I need to state the KKT conditions for the following problem:

Minimise $x_1^2 + 2x_2^2$ subject to $(x_1-1)^2 + x_2^2 \le 1$ and $x_2 = 1$.

I have that these conditions are:

$f(x^*) \le 0$

$h(x^*) = 0$

$\lambda^* \ge 0$

$\lambda^*_if_i(x^*) = 0$ where $1 \le i \le m$

$\nabla_xf(x^*) + \sum^m_{i=1}\lambda^*_i\nabla_xf_i^*(x^*) + \sum^l_{j=1}\mu^*_j\nabla_xh_j(x^*) = 0$

I have the first three conditions for this problem:

$(x_1-1)^2 + x_2^2 \le 1$

$x_2 = 1$

$\lambda \ge 0$

But I don't know how to approach the last two conditions. Please can someone help me understand how to achieve the final conditions.

Comment: Are you sure about the $x_2=1$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb It's definitely a constraint. Or are you asking if I'm sure it's a KKT condition?

Comment: This with the $(x_1-1)^2+x_2^2\leq1$ constraint implies $x_1=1$, and there is nothing to optimize?

Comment: Just compute the partial derivatives then plug them in and you are done.

Comment: @Solitary Partial derivatives of the constraints? And then plug it into the problem?

Comment: You have already listed the general KKT condition, so what you need to do are just evaluate the expressions in that condition for this particular optimization problem and plug in. For example, compute $\nabla_x f(x)$, etc.

Comment: @Solitary I'm not sure if I'm computing them correctly. I'm getting $2x_1 +\lambda(2x_1-2) = 0$ and $4x_2 + \lambda2x_2 =+\mu = 0$. Does that look correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Solitary Thank you for your help!! I've been told I'm still missing one KKT condition. Is that true?

Comment: I think what you listed are complete.